# How to use selenium to handle and select elements from the popup/hidden form/table?

Tags: python, selenium

I would like to select the popup date table/calendar from the below website by using selenium. i tried to add double click function in it, but it was failed to select the date that i wanted.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
ccass = driver.get('http://www.hkexnews.hk/sdw/search/searchsdw_c.aspx')
ticker = '00001'
menu = driver.find_element_by_xpath("#date-picker-popup").click()
ccass_search_year = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[1]/ul/li[2]/button').click()
actions.double_click(ccass_search_year)
ccass_search_month = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[2]/ul/li[4]/button').click()
actions.double_click(ccass_search_month)
ccass_search_day =  driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[3]/ul/li[4]/button').click()
actions.double_click(ccass_search_day)
ccass_search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtStockCode"]').send_keys(ticker) #Keys.ENTER) 
ccass_search_click = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnSearch"]').click()
```

Comment: What date does it select? Or does it not select any date?

Comment: i want to select 3rd April 2018

Answer (score 0):

The date you are trying to select is disabled. You can't select **3rd April 2018**. You can only select from 10th April and I'm guessing that it will be disabled tomorrow.

Sorry to say, you are too late. Which the class name for the disabled dates also.

Comment: i've edited the original code by adding the dictionary to classify the year, month and date.

Answer (score 0):

i edited for a little bit, the problem was that although i found all those buttons from the popup date picker, but i could not get the result of the date that i selected:

```
  year = year_list['2019']
  month = month_list['4']
  day = day_list['4']

  year_list = {'2018':'//*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[1]/ul/li[1]/button', '2019':'//*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[1]/ul/li[2]/button'}
  month_list = {'1':'//*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[2]/ul/li[1]/button', '2':'//*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[2]/ul/li[2]/button', '3':'//*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[2]/ul/li[3]/button', '4':'//*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[2]/ul/li[4]/button', '5':'//*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[2]/ul/li[5]/button', '6':'//*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[2]/ul/li[6]/button', '7':'//*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[2]/ul/li[7]/button', '8':'//*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[2]/ul/li[8]/button', '9':'//*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[2]/ul/li[9]/button', '10':'//*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[2]/ul/li[10]/button', '11':'//*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[2]/ul/li[11]/button', '12':'//*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[2]/ul/li[12]/button'}
  day_list = {'1':' //*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[3]/ul/li[1]/button','2':' //*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[3]/ul/li[2]/button','3':' //*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[3]/ul/li[3]/button','4':' //*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[3]/ul/li[4]/button','5':' //*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[3]/ul/li[5]/button','6':' //*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[3]/ul/li[6]/button','7':' //*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[3]/ul/li[7]/button','8':' //*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[3]/ul/li[8]/button','9':' //*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[3]/ul/li[9]/button','10':' //*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[3]/ul/li[10]/button','11':' //*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[3]/ul/li[11]/button','12':' //*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[3]/ul/li[12]/button','13':' //*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[3]/ul/li[13]/button','14':' //*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[3]/ul/li[14]/button','15':' //*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[3]/ul/li[15]/button','16':' //*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[3]/ul/li[16]/button','17':' //*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[3]/ul/li[17]/button','18':' //*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[3]/ul/li[18]/button','19':' //*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[3]/ul/li[19]/button','20':' //*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[3]/ul/li[20]/button','21':' //*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[3]/ul/li[21]/button','22':' //*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[3]/ul/li[22]/button','23':' //*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[3]/ul/li[23]/button','24':' //*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[3]/ul/li[24]/button','25':' //*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[3]/ul/li[25]/button','26':' //*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[3]/ul/li[26]/button','27':' //*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[3]/ul/li[27]/button','28':' //*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[3]/ul/li[28]/button','29':' //*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[3]/ul/li[29]/button','30':' //*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[3]/ul/li[30]/button','31':' //*[@id="date-picker"]/div[1]/b[3]/ul/li[31]/button'}

  ccass = driver.get('http://www.hkexnews.hk/sdw/search/searchsdw_c.aspx')
  popup_datepicker = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtShareholdingDate"]').click()

  ccass_search_year = driver.find_element_by_xpath(year).click()
  actions.double_click(ccass_search_year)

  ccass_search_month = driver.find_element_by_xpath(month).click()
  actions.double_click(ccass_search_month)

  ccass_search_day = driver.find_element_by_xpath(day).click()
  actions.double_click(ccass_search_day)

  ccass_search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtStockCode"]').send_keys(ticker) #Keys.ENTER) 
  ccass_search_click = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnSearch"]').click()
```